# Implementing Pollard's Rho Algorithm for Discrete Logarithms

Tags: python, algorithm, cryptography

I am trying to implement Pollard's rho algorithm for computing discrete logarithms based on the description in the book [*Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective*](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/macaj/skola/teoriapoli/primes.pdf) by Richard Crandall and Carl Pomerance, section 5.2.2, page 232. Here is my Python code:

```
def dlog(g,t,p):
    # l such that g**l == t (mod p), with p prime
    # algorithm due to Crandall/Pomerance "Prime Numbers" sec 5.2.2
    from fractions import gcd
    def inverse(x, p): return pow(x, p-2, p)
    def f(xab):
        x, a, b = xab[0], xab[1], xab[2]
        if x < p/3:
            return [(t*x)%p, (a+1)%(p-1), b]
        if 2*p/3 < x:
            return [(g*x)%p, a, (b+1)%(p-1)]
        return [(x*x)%p, (2*a)%(p-1), (2*b)%(p-1)]
    i, j, k = 1, [1,0,0], f([1,0,0])
    while j[0] <> k[0]:
        print i, j, k
        i, j, k = i+1, f(j), f(f(k))
    print i, j, k
    d = gcd(j[1] - k[1], p - 1)
    if d == 1: return ((k[2]-j[2]) * inverse(j[1]-k[1],p-1)) % (p-1)
    m, l = 0, ((k[2]-j[2]) * inverse(j[1]-k[1],(p-1)/d)) % ((p-1)/d)
    while m <= d:
        print m, l
        if pow(g,l,p) == t: return l
        m, l = m+1, (l+((p-1)/d))%(p-1)
    return False
```

The code includes debugging output to show what is happening. You can run the code at [http://ideone.com/8lzzOf](http://ideone.com/8lzzOfX), where you will also see two test cases. The first test case, which follows the *d* > 1 path, calculates the correct value. The second test case, which follows the *d* == 1 path, fails.

Please help me find my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem 1

One thing that looks suspicious is this function:

```
def inverse(x, p): return pow(x, p-2, p)
```

This is computing a modular inverse of x modulo p using [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Using_Euler.27s_theorem).  This is fine if p is prime, but otherwise you need to raise x to the power phi(p)-1.

In your case you are calling this function with a modulo of p-1 which is going to be even and therefore give an incorrect inverse.

As phi(p-1) is hard to compute, it may be better to use the [extended Euclidean algorithm for computing the inverse instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

### Problem 2

Running your code for the case g=83, t=566, p=997 produces 977, while you were expecting 147.

In fact 977 is indeed a logarithm of 83 as we can see if we compute:

```
>>> pow(83,977,997)
566
```

but it is not the one you were expecting (147).

This is because the Pollard rho method requires g to be a generator of the group.  Unfortunately, 83 is not a generator of the group 1,2,..997 because pow(83,166,997)==1.  (In other words, after generating 166 elements of the group you start repeating elements.)

Comment: I knew that, dammit. I have a fixed version of the function at [http://ideone.com/wUORDz](http://ideone.com/wUORDz), which still fails to properly compute the _d_ = 1 case.

Comment: Re: Problem 2: Got it. Thanks!